# Java Coding Loops

Tags: java, loops

Here is the assignment:

In many Olympic sports, an athlete is given scores by a panel of judges. Scores can range from 0.0 (awful) to 10.0 (perfect). To ensure fairness, the highest and lowest scores are dropped, and the remaining scores are averaged to produce the athlete's overall score.

Ask the user for the following information, in this order:

The number of judges on the panel (an integer).
The score given by each judge, one by one (real numbers).
Compute the average of all scores except the highest and lowest (a real number). If two or more judges give the same lowest score, only one should be dropped (the same principle applies to ties for the highest score).

And here is my code.

```
public class Scores {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter number of judges.");
        int j = IO.readInt();

        while (j < 3) {
            IO.reportBadInput();
            System.out.println("Enter number of judges.");
            j = IO.readInt();
        }

        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double highest = 0.0;
        double lowest = 10.0;
        double score;
        double average;
        for (count = 0; count < j; count = count + 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter score of judge.");
            score = IO.readDouble();

            while (score > 10.0 || score < 0.0) {
                IO.reportBadInput();
                System.out.println("Enter score of judge.");
                score = IO.readDouble();
            }

            if (score > highest) {
                score = highest;
            } else if (score < lowest);
            {
                score = lowest;

                sum = sum + score - highest - lowest;
                average = sum / (j - 2);
                System.out.println(lowest);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, we can't import anything/use Scanner.

Comment: So what's `IO` then?

Comment: And suspicion falls immediately to `} else if (score < lowest);` ...

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Which errors are you getting and where are you getting them?

Comment: We have to use IO to read our codes. And the problem I'm having is my code won't assign highest to the highest #, nor will it assign lowest to the lowest #. And my average is incorrect.